# Images lose quality when I upload to Craft

Tags: assets, image

The images I upload to Craft lose their quality :(

Without applying any transformation, the original file is blurred and has a smaller size.

I read this on another question:

> Currently the images are being cleansed on upload, which means that they are being re-saved to make sure that no malicious code is injected in them.

**There is a way to get Craft uploading my pixel-perfect images without re-save them?**




An example of the problem:

[image: An example of the problem]

Comment: Do you have the [ImageMagick Extension](https://buildwithcraft.com/docs/requirements#optional-php-extensions) installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There is a way to get Craft uploading my pixel-perfect images without re-save them?

You can upload via FTP and then run the `Update Asset Indexes` tool from the Settings page in the control panel.

If you want to continue uploading from the control panel make sure that you're using [Imagick](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) instead of [GD](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).

Craft will use Imagick if it is available to PHP by default or you can force Craft to use one or the other via the [imageDriver](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#imageDriver) config setting.

Comment: Would this still be applicable to Craft 3? And any alternative to using Imagick? Can;t we just stop Craft editing images, I am having very bad loss of quality on a JPG.